# GCM register blocking AsyncTask until timeout occurs

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, google-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to get my device registration ID with GCM.  My code to do so is contained within an AsyncTask which is called from my main thread.

Main code

```
try
{
    String deviceId = new Gcm().execute(this.activity).get(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    Log.i("Login", "User device id returned as " + deviceId);
    return deviceId;
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Log.e("Login", "Exception", e);
}
```

GCM Class

```
public class Gcm extends AsyncTask<Activity,Void,String>
{

@Override
protected String doInBackground(Activity... params)
{
    Log.i("GCM", "Attempting to get device id");
    Activity activity = params[0];
    try
    {
        Log.i("GCM", "Getting GCM instance");
        GoogleCloudMessaging gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(activity.getApplicationContext());

        Log.i("GCM", "Registering with GCM");

        String regId = gcm.register(PROJECT_NUMBER);

        Log.i("GCM",  "Device registered, registration ID=" + regId);

        return regId;
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        throw new IllegalStateException(e);
    }
}
}
```

And here is my log dump

```
07-28 13:07:39.093  I/GCM﹕ Attempting to get device id
07-28 13:07:39.093  I/GCM﹕ Getting GCM instance
07-28 13:07:39.093  I/GCM﹕ Registering with GCM
07-28 13:07:44.103  E/Login﹕ Exception
    java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:176)
        at android.os.AsyncTask.get(AsyncTask.java:507)
I/GCM﹕ Device registered, registration ID=XXXXXX
```

So for some reason, calling gcm.register() is blocking until my timeout exception is hit.  Does anyone have any idea why that might be happening?

Comment: sounds like either an internet problem or a server problem.

Comment: What happens when you try to register with the new Instance API and GCM https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/client

Comment: but I'm getting a registration ID from the server, wouldn't that indicate my connectivity is OK?

Comment: I haven't tried that API yet, but I'll give it a shot

Comment: also never use `.get()` in an async task that block the UI thread and you dont want to do that

Comment: Please take a look at my answer, there's an example of registering GCM!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is cause you're executing gcm with

```
.get(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

This call blocks the thread for 5 seconds, however due to different reasons like unstable network connection the registration process can take more than 5 seconds. It is not the best approach to do what you want.

Take a look at this example, taken from [official GCM demo](https://github.com/google/gcm):

```
private void registerInBackground() {
    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>() {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            String msg = "";
            try {
                if (gcm == null) {
                    gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(context);
                }
                regid = gcm.register(SENDER_ID);
                msg = "Device registered, registration ID=" + regid;

                // You should send the registration ID to your server over HTTP, so it
                // can use GCM/HTTP or CCS to send messages to your app.
                sendRegistrationIdToBackend();

                // For this demo: we don't need to send it because the device will send
                // upstream messages to a server that echo back the message using the
                // 'from' address in the message.

                // Persist the regID - no need to register again.
                storeRegistrationId(context, regid);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                msg = "Error :" + ex.getMessage();
                // If there is an error, don't just keep trying to register.
                // Require the user to click a button again, or perform
                // exponential back-off.
            }
            return msg;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String msg) {
            mDisplay.append(msg + "\n");
        }
    }.execute(null, null, null);
```

Incorporate this example and everything should work.

Comment: Everything seems OK if I don't use get() and instead do some sort of callback through onPostExecute.  I was hoping I could make the call synchronously.  It seems all the feedback I'm getting is that that's a bad idea, so I'll abandon that implementation.

I'd still like to understand why I'm seeing this behavior, but for now I can at least continue along with my project :)

Comment: This behavior caused by forcing android to use main thread for task that should be on the background thread. And yes, often it takes more time to figure out 1 tiny error than to re-create whole class with other approach ;)

Answer (score 1):

Using an AsyncTask like that doesn't make sense. AsyncTasks are used to avoid blocking the thread, but by using the blocking get() call you are blocking the thread anyway. You may as well call register() directly in that case.

You are getting a timeout because you're blocking for 5s, but GCM is taking longer than 5s to register. This could be due to bad network conditions as it can take a while for a network request to time out. Or maybe it is just taking more than 5s to get the registration ID.

Comment: Even if I change the timeout to 20 seconds I see the same behavior, so it's not actually a network timeout.

07-28 13:29:26.127 I/GCM﹕ Registering with GCM

07-28 13:29:46.134 E/Login﹕ Exception
    java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException

07-28 13:29:46.147  I/GCM﹕ Device registered, registration ID=XXXX

Comment: Agree, it is not about changing the blocking interval. You just need to use slightly different approach

Comment: The problem is that get() causes the main thread to block. If the main thread is blocked, the GCM registration is never completed for some reason (maybe it has something to do with the lifecycle) and the app is effectively in a deadlock. You should get rid of the main thread blocking all together. The solution from @IvanV should work flawlessly.