# Calling Thread in the middle of function

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-studio

I am calling a thread that returns the GCM ID into a public variable called gcmRegID

the problems is that the thread only get called once the function has ended

I wonder if there is a way I can get the value of the gcmRegID in the middle of the function

I will explain more by code

I want to get the value of gcmRegID in CheckGCMID  but what I get is ""

```
String gcmRegID = "";
public void onClick(View view) {
    String CheckGCMID;
    GetGCM();
    CheckGCMID = gcmRegID; // <-- This is always return empty string
}

private void GetGCM() {
    Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                GCMHelper gcmRegistrationHelper = new GCMHelper(
                        getApplicationContext());
                gcmRegID = gcmRegistrationHelper.GCMRegister("123456");
                // gcmRegID value is "KHDKJDIUHDHDKDK"
            } catch (Exception bug) {
                bug.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });

    thread.start();
}
```

Comment: try to store the id in `gcmID` when you call the method `getGcm()` like `gcmID=getGcm();`

Comment: Take an AsyncTask like in http://stackoverflow.com/a/31686447 and do whatever you need to do when you have the result from within the `onPostExecute` method.

Comment: Like zapl said, this is asynchrone, Don't use a Thread if you want to stay synchrone. And you should read about camelCase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a Callback to get your value async.

Try something like this:

```
public void onClick(View view) {

            String CheckGCMID;
            GetGCM(new MyCallback(){
                @Override
                public void receivedString(String myString) {
                    //use your id here
                    System.out.println(myString);
                }
            });

  }


private interface MyCallback{
    public void receivedString(String myString);
}

private void GetGCM(MyCallback callback) {
    Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                GCMHelper  gcmRegistrationHelper = new GCMHelper (getApplicationContext());
                String gcmRegID = gcmRegistrationHelper.GCMRegister("123456");
                callback.receivedString(gcmRegID);
            } catch (Exception bug) {
                bug.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    });
    thread.start();
}
```

Comment: what does not work? you should use the received id only in the callback method.